# How do you perform a RegExp query on a URL in ElasticSearch?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to perform (what I consider to be) a simple RegExp query in ElasticSearch, but for the life of me I can't get it to work. Here is said query,

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp":{
      "request_url": "/somepage/[0-9]+/[a-z]+"
    }
  }
}
```

Where this query seems to break is when I include a forward slash `/` character. Without the forward slashes, I get results for each of the individual parts.

I've tried just a slash `/`, I've tried escaping it with `\/` and `\\/`. I reduced the query to `/somepage` and `\\/somepage`, nothing.

I've been Googling heavily on this, and I can't seem to find a consistent answer. I *think* maybe ElasticSearch just doesn't support `/` in RegExp queries...? I know from looking at the docs that it isn't a reserved character.

Could it be something to do with the datatype of this field?

```
"request_url": {
  "type": "text",
  "norms": false,
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "ignore_above": 256
    }
  }
},
```

Looking at the docs, `text` explicitly says it analyses and tokenises the data. So I expect it may be dropping the `/` characters? I tried the query against the `keyword` field as well, and it didn't work.

So, any suggestions? Can ElasticSearch actually do what I need? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions:

1. `\\\\/` if that was treated as a string it would become `\\/` in JSON, that at the same time, would become `\/`
2. `\x2f` and derivatives => `\\x2f` or `\\\\x2f`